# Automator Newbie question

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I'm running my Mac under 10.9.2 and have about 75 scanned Tiff files which need to be processed through the OCR app, TesseractGUI 0.3. It works very well for me but balks at .tiff extensions and Alpha enabled files. In small batches I've been using Preview to Export, deleting the second "f" and unchecking the Alpha. This manual file adjustment works well.

Time to put Automator to use. I've gone through Apple's "Basic Tutorial" but there's not enough detail to find my way. I've been having a devil of a time getting inexplicable running errors.

I've conceived of a routine where whatever is put in a "Process" folder on the desktop will automatically delete the second "f" in the extension and uncheck the Alpha. Then move the revised file to a "Processed" folder also on the desktop. That way I'd still have my unchanged originals as well as files TesseractGUI will accept.

Appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a Terminal command to batch edit the extensions and move the files to the processed folder:

> cd /path/to/folder

where /path/to/folder is the folder containing the originals.

> for file in *.tiff; do cp "$file" "${file%tiff}tif"; mv *.tif ~/Desktop/Processed; done

This command will leave the originals in the original folder, and move the "processed (tif)" files to the "Processed" folder. The script is a bit sloppy regarding syntax, but would easily get the job done. I don't know how to automate unchecking "Alpha."

Note that you can incorporate Shell commands into an Automator routine as well, under Library > Utilities > Run Shell Script.

Comment: Given it a try, but my understanding of terminal syntax is too limited to make it work. Here's the results:Morley-Chalmers-iMac:~ morleychalmers$ cd /path/to/folder
-bash: cd: /path/to/folder: No such file or directory
Morley-Chalmers-iMac:~ morleychalmers$ cd/path/to/folder
-bash: cd/path/to/folder: No such file or directory
Morley-Chalmers-iMac:~ morleychalmers$ for file in *.tiff; do cp "$file" "${file%tiff}tif"; mv *.tif ~/Desktop/Processed; done
cp: *.tiff: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.tif to /Users/morleychalmers/Desktop/Processed/*.tif: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm simultaneously attempting to solve a problem and at the same time learn how apple.stackexchange works. This is my first question. After the above failed attempt to use Terminal I then tried to use Automator to record my manual procedure using the File>Export command in Preview. Take the second F off of tiff and uncheck the Alpha option. Saved it as a Automator workflow document. Realistically I know I'm flailing about with too little understanding of these tools.

Comment: @user77681 replace `/path/to/folder` with the actual path to your "Process" folder.  One way of doing this is to drag the folder into the Terminal window itself. To learn how to use the Terminal on OS X, I recommend [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025870.do).